# Integrate web content page on lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, colorbox

I have two pages: the first contains a button when clicked it appears a lightbox. i want to get the content of the second page an put it on lightbox

page1

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $(".inline").colorbox({ inline: true, width: "50%" });

       })
   </script>
   <title></title>
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>Colorbox Demonstration</h1>
  <p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a></p>
  <div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
        <p><strong>This content comes from a hidden element on this page.</strong></p>
        <p>The inline option preserves bound JavaScript events and changes, and it puts the content back where it came from when it is closed.</p>
        <p><a id="click" href="#" style='padding:5px; background:#ccc;'>btn1</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div style='display:none'>
        <div id='test' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
            <p>The inline option preserves bound JavaScript events and changes.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

jquery.colorbox.js

```
   (function ($, document, window) {
          var

          defaults = {

            html: false,
            photo: false,
            iframe: false,
            inline: false,

            transition: "elastic",
            speed: 300,
            fadeOut: 300,
            width: false,
            initialWidth: "600",
            innerWidth: false,
            maxWidth: false,
            height: false,
            initialHeight: "450",
            innerHeight: false,
            maxHeight: false,
            scrolling: true,
            opacity: 0.9,
            preloading: true,
            className: false,
            overlayClose: true,
            escKey: true,
            arrowKey: true,
            top: false,
            bottom: false,
            left: false,
            right: false,
            fixed: false,
            closeButton: true,
            fastIframe: true,
            open: false,

            href: function() {
              return $(this).attr('href');
            },


            createIframe: function() {
              var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
              var attrs = $(this).data('cbox-iframe-attrs');

              if (typeof attrs === 'object') {
                $.each(attrs, function(key, val){
                  iframe[key] = val;
                });
              }
              return iframe;
            }
          },

          colorbox = 'colorbox',
          prefix = 'cbox',
          boxElement = prefix + 'Element',

          event_open = prefix + '_open',
          event_load = prefix + '_load',
          event_complete = prefix + '_complete',
          event_cleanup = prefix + '_cleanup',
          event_closed = prefix + '_closed',
          event_purge = prefix + '_purge',

          $overlay,
          $box,
          $wrap,
          $content,
          $topBorder,
          $leftBorder,
          $rightBorder,
          $bottomBorder,
          $related,
          $window,
          $loaded,
          $loadingBay,
          $loadingOverlay,
          $title,
          $current,
          $slideshow,
          $next,
          $prev,
          $close,
          $groupControls,
          $events = $('<a/>'),

          settings,
          interfaceHeight,
          interfaceWidth,
          loadedHeight,
          loadedWidth,
          index,
          photo,
          open,
          active,
          closing,
          loadingTimer,
          publicMethod,
          div = "div",
          requests = 0,
          previousCSS = {},
          init;

          function $tag(tag, id, css) {
            var element = document.createElement(tag);

            if (id) {
              element.id = prefix + id;
            }

            if (css) {
              element.style.cssText = css;
            }

            return $(element);
          }

          function winheight() {
            return window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
          }

          function Settings(element, options) {
            if (options !== Object(options)) {
              options = {};
            }

            this.cache = {};
            this.el = element;

            this.value = function(key) {
              var dataAttr;

              if (this.cache[key] === undefined) {
                dataAttr = $(this.el).attr('data-cbox-'+key);

                if (dataAttr !== undefined) {
                  this.cache[key] = dataAttr;
                } else if (options[key] !== undefined) {
                  this.cache[key] = options[key];
                } else if (defaults[key] !== undefined) {
                  this.cache[key] = defaults[key];
                }
              }

              return this.cache[key];
            };

            this.get = function(key) {
              var value = this.value(key);
              return $.isFunction(value) ? value.call(this.el, this) : value;
            };
          }

          function setSize(size, dimension) {
            return Math.round((/%/.test(size) ? ((dimension === 'x' ? $window.width() : winheight()) / 100) : 1) * parseInt(size, 10));
          }

          function setClass(str) {
            if (setClass.str !== str) {
              $box.add($overlay).removeClass(setClass.str).addClass(str);
              setClass.str = str;
            }
          }

          function getRelated(rel) {
            index = 0;

            if (rel && rel !== false && rel !== 'nofollow') {
              $related = $('.' + boxElement).filter(function () {
                var options = $.data(this, colorbox);
                var settings = new Settings(this, options);
                return (settings.get('rel') === rel);
              });
              index = $related.index(settings.el);

              if (index === -1) {
                $related = $related.add(settings.el);
                index = $related.length - 1;
              }
            } else {
              $related = $(settings.el);
            }
          }

          function trigger(event) {
            // for external use
            $(document).trigger(event);
            // for internal use
            $events.triggerHandler(event);
          };

          function launch(element) {
            var options;

            if (!closing) {

              options = $(element).data(colorbox);

              settings = new Settings(element, options);

              getRelated(settings.get('rel'));

              if (!open) {
                open = active = true;

                setClass(settings.get('className'));

                $box.css({visibility:'hidden', display:'block', opacity:''});

                $loaded = $tag(div, 'LoadedContent', 'width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden');
                $content.css({width:'', height:''}).append($loaded);

                interfaceHeight = $topBorder.height() + $bottomBorder.height() + $content.outerHeight(true) - $content.height();
                interfaceWidth = $leftBorder.width() + $rightBorder.width() + $content.outerWidth(true) - $content.width();
                loadedHeight = $loaded.outerHeight(true);
                loadedWidth = $loaded.outerWidth(true);

                var initialWidth = setSize(settings.get('initialWidth'), 'x');
                var initialHeight = setSize(settings.get('initialHeight'), 'y');
                var maxWidth = settings.get('maxWidth');
                var maxHeight = settings.get('maxHeight');

                settings.w = Math.max((maxWidth !== false ? Math.min(initialWidth, setSize(maxWidth, 'x')) : initialWidth) - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth, 0);
                settings.h = Math.max((maxHeight !== false ? Math.min(initialHeight, setSize(maxHeight, 'y')) : initialHeight) - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight, 0);

                $loaded.css({width:'', height:settings.h});
                publicMethod.position();

                trigger(event_open);
                settings.get('onOpen');

                $groupControls.add($title).hide();

                $box.focus();


                if (settings.get('returnFocus')) {
                  $events.one(event_closed, function () {
                    $(settings.el).focus();
                  });
                }
              }

              var opacity = parseFloat(settings.get('opacity'));
              $overlay.css({
                opacity: opacity === opacity ? opacity : '',
                cursor: settings.get('overlayClose') ? 'pointer' : '',
                visibility: 'visible'
              }).show();

              if (settings.get('closeButton')) {
                $close.html(settings.get('close')).appendTo($content);
              } else {
                $close.appendTo('<div/>');
              }

              load();
            }
          }

          function appendHTML() {
            if (!$box) {
              init = false;
              $window = $(window);
              $box = $tag(div).attr({
                id: colorbox,
                'class': $.support.opacity === false ? prefix + 'IE' : '', 
                role: 'dialog',
                tabindex: '-1'
              }).hide();
              $overlay = $tag(div, "Overlay").hide();
              $loadingOverlay = $([$tag(div, "LoadingOverlay")[0],$tag(div, "LoadingGraphic")[0]]);
              $wrap = $tag(div, "Wrapper");
              $content = $tag(div, "Content").append(
                $title = $tag(div, "Title"),
                $current = $tag(div, "Current"),
                $prev = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:prefix+'Previous'}),
                $next = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:prefix+'Next'}),
                $slideshow = $tag('button', "Slideshow"),
                $loadingOverlay
              );

              $close = $('<button type="button"/>').attr({id:prefix+'Close'});

              $wrap.append(
                $tag(div).append(
                  $tag(div, "TopLeft"),
                  $topBorder = $tag(div, "TopCenter"),
                  $tag(div, "TopRight")
                ),
                $tag(div, false, 'clear:left').append(
                  $leftBorder = $tag(div, "MiddleLeft"),
                  $content,
                  $rightBorder = $tag(div, "MiddleRight")
                ),
                $tag(div, false, 'clear:left').append(
                  $tag(div, "BottomLeft"),
                  $bottomBorder = $tag(div, "BottomCenter"),
                  $tag(div, "BottomRight")
                )
              ).find('div div').css({'float': 'left'});

              $loadingBay = $tag(div, false, 'position:absolute; width:9999px; visibility:hidden; display:none; max-width:none;');

              $groupControls = $next.add($prev).add($current).add($slideshow);
            }
            if (document.body && !$box.parent().length) {
              $(document.body).append($overlay, $box.append($wrap, $loadingBay));
            }
          }

          function addBindings() {
            function clickHandler(e) {
              if (!(e.which > 1 || e.shiftKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                launch(this);
              }
            }

            if ($box) {
              if (!init) {
                init = true;

                $next.click(function () {
                  publicMethod.next();
                });
                $prev.click(function () {
                  publicMethod.prev();
                });
                $close.click(function () {
                  publicMethod.close();
                });
                $overlay.click(function () {
                  if (settings.get('overlayClose')) {
                    publicMethod.close();
                  }
                });

                $(document).bind('keydown.' + prefix, function (e) {
                  var key = e.keyCode;
                  if (open && settings.get('escKey') && key === 27) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    publicMethod.close();
                  }
                  if (open && settings.get('arrowKey') && $related[1] && !e.altKey) {
                    if (key === 37) {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      $prev.click();
                    } else if (key === 39) {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      $next.click();
                    }
                  }
                });

                if ($.isFunction($.fn.on)) {
                  $(document).on('click.'+prefix, '.'+boxElement, clickHandler);
                } else {

                  $('.'+boxElement).live('click.'+prefix, clickHandler);
                }
              }
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          }

          if ($[colorbox]) {
            return;
          }

          $(appendHTML);

          publicMethod = $.fn[colorbox] = $[colorbox] = function (options, callback) {
            var settings;
            var $obj = this;

            options = options || {};

            if ($.isFunction($obj)) {
              $obj = $('<a/>');
              options.open = true;
            }

            if (!$obj[0]) {
              return $obj;
            }

            appendHTML();

            if (addBindings()) {

              if (callback) {
                options.onComplete = callback;
              }

              $obj.each(function () {
                var old = $.data(this, colorbox) || {};
                $.data(this, colorbox, $.extend(old, options));
              }).addClass(boxElement);

              settings = new Settings($obj[0], options);

              if (settings.get('open')) {
                launch($obj[0]);
              }
            }

            return $obj;
          };

          publicMethod.position = function (speed, loadedCallback) {
            var
            css,
            top = 0,
            left = 0,
            offset = $box.offset(),
            scrollTop,
            scrollLeft;

            $window.unbind('resize.' + prefix);
            $box.css({top: -9e4, left: -9e4});

            scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
            scrollLeft = $window.scrollLeft();

            if (settings.get('fixed')) {
              offset.top -= scrollTop;
              offset.left -= scrollLeft;
              $box.css({position: 'fixed'});
            } else {
              top = scrollTop;
              left = scrollLeft;
              $box.css({position: 'absolute'});
            }

            if (settings.get('right') !== false) {
              left += Math.max($window.width() - settings.w - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth - setSize(settings.get('right'), 'x'), 0);
            } else if (settings.get('left') !== false) {
              left += setSize(settings.get('left'), 'x');
            } else {
              left += Math.round(Math.max($window.width() - settings.w - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth, 0) / 2);
            }

            if (settings.get('bottom') !== false) {
              top += Math.max(winheight() - settings.h - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight - setSize(settings.get('bottom'), 'y'), 0);
            } else if (settings.get('top') !== false) {
              top += setSize(settings.get('top'), 'y');
            } else {
              top += Math.round(Math.max(winheight() - settings.h - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight, 0) / 2);
            }

            $box.css({top: offset.top, left: offset.left, visibility:'visible'});

            $wrap[0].style.width = $wrap[0].style.height = "9999px";

            function modalDimensions() {
              $topBorder[0].style.width = $bottomBorder[0].style.width = $content[0].style.width = (parseInt($box[0].style.width,10) - interfaceWidth)+'px';
              $content[0].style.height = $leftBorder[0].style.height = $rightBorder[0].style.height = (parseInt($box[0].style.height,10) - interfaceHeight)+'px';
            }

            css = {width: settings.w + loadedWidth + interfaceWidth, height: settings.h + loadedHeight + interfaceHeight, top: top, left: left};

            if (speed) {
              var tempSpeed = 0;
              $.each(css, function(i){
                if (css[i] !== previousCSS[i]) {
                  tempSpeed = speed;
                  return;
                }
              });
              speed = tempSpeed;
            }

            previousCSS = css;

            if (!speed) {
              $box.css(css);
            }

            $box.dequeue().animate(css, {
              duration: speed || 0,
              complete: function () {
                modalDimensions();

                active = false;

                $wrap[0].style.width = (settings.w + loadedWidth + interfaceWidth) + "px";
                $wrap[0].style.height = (settings.h + loadedHeight + interfaceHeight) + "px";

                if (settings.get('reposition')) {
                  setTimeout(function () {
                    $window.bind('resize.' + prefix, publicMethod.position);
                  }, 1);
                }

                if ($.isFunction(loadedCallback)) {
                  loadedCallback();
                }
              },
              step: modalDimensions
            });
          };

          publicMethod.resize = function (options) {
            var scrolltop;

            if (open) {
              options = options || {};

              if (options.width) {
                settings.w = setSize(options.width, 'x') - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth;
              }

              if (options.innerWidth) {
                settings.w = setSize(options.innerWidth, 'x');
              }

              $loaded.css({width: settings.w});

              if (options.height) {
                settings.h = setSize(options.height, 'y') - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight;
              }

              if (options.innerHeight) {
                settings.h = setSize(options.innerHeight, 'y');
              }

              if (!options.innerHeight && !options.height) {
                scrolltop = $loaded.scrollTop();
                $loaded.css({height: "auto"});
                settings.h = $loaded.height();
              }

              $loaded.css({height: settings.h});

              if(scrolltop) {
                $loaded.scrollTop(scrolltop);
              }

              publicMethod.position(settings.get('transition') === "none" ? 0 : settings.get('speed'));
            }
          };

          publicMethod.prep = function (object) {
            if (!open) {
              return;
            }

            var callback, speed = settings.get('transition') === "none" ? 0 : settings.get('speed');
            $loaded.remove();
            $loaded = $tag(div, 'LoadedContent').append(object);

            function getWidth() {
              settings.w = settings.w || $loaded.width();
              settings.w = settings.mw && settings.mw < settings.w ? settings.mw : settings.w;
              return settings.w;
            }
            function getHeight() {
              settings.h = settings.h || $loaded.height();
              settings.h = settings.mh && settings.mh < settings.h ? settings.mh : settings.h;
              return settings.h;
            }

            $loaded.hide()
            .appendTo($loadingBay.show())
            .css({width: getWidth(), overflow: settings.get('scrolling') ? 'auto' : 'hidden'})
            .css({height: getHeight()})
            .prependTo($content);
            $loadingBay.hide();
            $(photo).css({'float': 'none'});

            setClass(settings.get('className'));

            callback = function () {
              var total = $related.length,
                iframe,
                complete;

              if (!open) {
                return;
              }

              function removeFilter() {
                if ($.support.opacity === false) {
                  $box[0].style.removeAttribute('filter');
                }
              }

              complete = function () {
                clearTimeout(loadingTimer);
                $loadingOverlay.hide();
                trigger(event_complete);
                settings.get('onComplete');
              };

              $title.html(settings.get('title')).show();
              $loaded.show();

              if (total > 1) {
                if (typeof settings.get('current') === "string") {
                  $current.html(settings.get('current').replace('{current}', index + 1).replace('{total}', total)).show();
                }

                $next[(settings.get('loop') || index < total - 1) ? "show" : "hide"]().html(settings.get('next'));
                $prev[(settings.get('loop') || index) ? "show" : "hide"]().html(settings.get('previous'));

              } else {
                $groupControls.hide();
              }

              if (settings.get('iframe')) {

                iframe = settings.get('createIframe');

                if (!settings.get('scrolling')) {
                  iframe.scrolling = "no";
                }

                $(iframe)
                  .attr({
                    src: settings.get('href'),
                    'class': prefix + 'Iframe'
                  })
                  .one('load', complete)
                  .appendTo($loaded);

                $events.one(event_purge, function () {
                  iframe.src = "//about:blank";
                });

                if (settings.get('fastIframe')) {
                  $(iframe).trigger('load');
                }
              } else {
                complete();
              }

              if (settings.get('transition') === 'fade') {
                $box.fadeTo(speed, 1, removeFilter);
              } else {
                removeFilter();
              }
            };

            if (settings.get('transition') === 'fade') {
              $box.fadeTo(speed, 0, function () {
                publicMethod.position(0, callback);
              });
            } else {
              publicMethod.position(speed, callback);
            }
          };

          function load () {
            var href, setResize, prep = publicMethod.prep, $inline, request = ++requests;

            active = true;
            photo = false;

            trigger(event_purge);
            trigger(event_load);
            settings.get('onLoad');

            settings.h = settings.get('height') ?
                setSize(settings.get('height'), 'y') - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight :
                settings.get('innerHeight') && setSize(settings.get('innerHeight'), 'y');

            settings.w = settings.get('width') ?
                setSize(settings.get('width'), 'x') - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth :
                settings.get('innerWidth') && setSize(settings.get('innerWidth'), 'x');

            settings.mw = settings.w;
            settings.mh = settings.h;

            if (settings.get('maxWidth')) {
              settings.mw = setSize(settings.get('maxWidth'), 'x') - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth;
              settings.mw = settings.w && settings.w < settings.mw ? settings.w : settings.mw;
            }
            if (settings.get('maxHeight')) {
              settings.mh = setSize(settings.get('maxHeight'), 'y') - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight;
              settings.mh = settings.h && settings.h < settings.mh ? settings.h : settings.mh;
            }

            href = settings.get('href');
            loadingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
              $loadingOverlay.show();
            }, 100);

            if (settings.get('inline')) {
              var $target = $(href);
              $inline = $('<div>').hide().insertBefore($target);
              $events.one(event_purge, function () {
                $inline.replaceWith($target);
              });
              prep($target);
            } else if (settings.get('iframe')) {

              prep(" ");
            } else if (settings.get('html')) {
              prep(settings.get('html'));
            }
          }

          publicMethod.next = function () {
            if (!active && $related[1] && (settings.get('loop') || $related[index + 1])) {
              index = getIndex(1);
              launch($related[index]);
            }
          };


          publicMethod.close = function () {
            if (open && !closing) {

              closing = true;
              open = false;
              trigger(event_cleanup);
              settings.get('onCleanup');
              $window.unbind('.' + prefix);
              $overlay.fadeTo(settings.get('fadeOut') || 0, 0);

              $box.stop().fadeTo(settings.get('fadeOut') || 0, 0, function () {
                $box.hide();
                $overlay.hide();
                trigger(event_purge);
                $loaded.remove();

                setTimeout(function () {
                  closing = false;
                  trigger(event_closed);
                  settings.get('onClosed');
                }, 1);
              });
            }
          };
          publicMethod.element = function () {
            return $(settings.el);
          };
        }(jQuery, document, window));
```

page2

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8"/>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   dfdfdffdfdfdf
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to integrate the content of html page2 on a lightbox of page1

Answer (score 0):

try to use it,

`iframe: true`, when `$(document).ready` function